# Magento - Getting media Gallery images from product

Tags: magento

In the file catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml i am trying to create an array like

```
<?php
        $arrayImages=array();
        foreach ($_product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
            $var= Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $image->getFile())->resize(265);
            $arrayImages[$image->getLabel()]=$var;
        } 

?>
```

Ideally this array should be like

```
array([imagelabel]=>'image url',[imagelabel 2]=>'image url 2',....)
```

but what i am getting is

```
array([imagelabel]=>'an object  Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image Object', ...)
```

When i try to echo the $var variable inside the foreach loop i am getting the Image urls properly but when i try to assign it into an array i get this issue..

Please help me out...

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
$arrayImages[$image->getLabel()]=$var;
```

to this:

```
$arrayImages[$image->getLabel()]=(string)$var;
```